# Concatenate a few cells and creating a link from concatenation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a script where by assume
Column I contains Address
Column J contains City
Column K contains Zip code
Assume the there are thousands of entries

I wanted a script that would concatenate these values and create a google maps link on column I itself.

I did manage to get the link part working partly but could not get it to concatenate it before creating the link.

```
function googlemaps() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var r = ss.getActiveRange() + ss.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, 1, 2);
// var t = r.offset(1, 0, 2);
var v = r.getValues();
for(var i=0;i<v.length;i++) {
for(var j=0;j<v[0].length;j++) {
  v[i][j] = '=HYPERLINK("http://google.com/maps/places/'+v[i][j]+'","'+v[i][j]+'")'
  }
 }
r.setValues(v);  
};
```

It keeps giving me this error

```
 // typeError: Cannot find function getValues in object RangeRange
```

I know it's the offset thing but I can't get it to work.
An example of what i want would be

```
I3 = 1515 SW 2 CT
J3 = Miami
K3 = 33196
```

And with this script run, it would change I in

```
=hyperlink("http://google.com/maps/places/1515 SW 2 CT Miami 33196", "1515 SW 2 CT")
```

should be able to work across a range.

Anyone please help.

I tried this as well:

```
function googlemaps() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var r = ss.getActiveRange();
var r2 = ss.getActiveRange().offset(0, 1);
var r3 = ss.getActiveRange().offset(0, 2);
var v = r.getValues();
var v1= r2.getValues();
var v2= r3.getValues();
var vf= v + v1 + v2;
for(var i=0;i<vf.length;i++) {
for(var j=0;j<vf[0].length;j++) {
  vf[i][j] = '=HYPERLINK("http://google.com/maps/places/'+vf[i][j]+'","'+vf[i][j]+'")'
}
}
r.setValues(vf);  
};
```

and that does not work as well, gives me the error Cannot find method setValues(string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do this with just a formula.

```
I3 = 1515 SW 2 CT
J3 = Miami
K3 = 33196
L3 = =HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("http://maps.google.com/maps?   f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=",I3," ",J3," ",K3),"Google Map")
```

Sorry I did not understand your requirement. Try this.

```
function googlemaps() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow()
var r = ss.getSheetValues(3,9,lr-2,3);//Assunes address data starts on row 3
for(var i=0;i<lr-2;i++) {
var addr = r[i][0]+' ' +r[i][1]+' ' +r[i][2] // Concatenates address data
r[i][9] = '=HYPERLINK("http://maps.google.com/maps?   f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q='+addr+'","'+addr+'")'
ss.getRange(i+3,9).setFormula(r[i][9]);
ss.getRange(i+3,10).clear(); //Clears City
ss.getRange(i+3,11).clear(); //Clears Zip
}
};
```

Here is another version than creates an array of the hyperlinks and writes them back once instead of a row at a time. It is much faster. I tested it with 4000 addresses. Also, I changed it to start on row 2 (assuming a header row). If you need to adjust where it starts, Google setRange(1,1,1,1) notation for an explaination of what each number means. It controls the start row. Also the lr-1 would need to be changed if you change the start row so the total number of rows will be correct.

```
function googlemaps1() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var lr = ss.getLastRow()
var r = ss.getSheetValues(2,9,lr-1,3);//Assunes address data starts on row 2
var arr = []
for(var i=0;i<lr-1;i++) {
var addr = r[i][0]+' ' +r[i][1]+' ' +r[i][2] // Concatenates address data
r[i][9] = '=HYPERLINK("http://maps.google.com/maps? f=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q='+addr+'","'+addr+'")'
 arr.push([r[i][9]])
 }
 var clr =  ss.getRange(2,10,arr.length,2).clear();//clear state and zip
 var destrange = ss.getRange(2,9,arr.length,1);
 destrange.setFormulas(arr);// set all hyperlinks
 };
```

Comment: I can't unfortunately do that, because These data are being pulled from another plugin and I can't change or add anycolumn. I initially wanted to do that but could not

Comment: Hi that works, but could we get it to run on a range that I select rather than making it work from beginning until last row? As I have 7000 entries and it takes forever to run.

I changed 

    var lr = ss.getLastRow()

to 

    var lr= ss.getactiveRange()

but it gives me 

     Cannot convert NaN to (class)

Comment: I changed it to var lr=ss.getActiveRange().getLastRow() and it works, the only problem now it always processes as from row 3

Comment: Try this revision. It will be MUCH faster. Let me know if you have problems.

Comment: Another question. What is the issue with the start row? Are new addresses added at the end of your list of already converted hyperlinks? If so, I can show you how to find the new start row. If you could post a sample spreadsheet it would help resolve your issue. I think selecting an active range is going to cause problems with the range size posting back the array.

Comment: That works. I realized it's much better to just do everything one shot.